# Calling functions in jenkinsfile with variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need some help in calling a function in `Jenkinsfile` along with a variable.
I have created a bash function to copy certain test results from jenkins slave to Jenkins master's `userContent` directory.
I want to use this function across diff jobs. Different jobs might have different report path, instead of hardcoding the path inside the function i want to use a variable in jenkinsfile to pass along with the function.
Here is my function:

```
def call() {
  sh '''
    mkdir -p $JOB_NAME
    foldername="$BUILD_NUMBER.$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')"
    echo ${foldername}
    mkdir -p $JOB_NAME/${foldername}
    pwd
    reportPath=""
    dest="./$JOB_NAME/${foldername}"
    cp -R ${reportPath}/*.xml ${dest}
    scp -r $JOB_NAME jenkins@master_ip:/var/lib/jenkins/userContent/
    '''   
}
```

How do i call the function in jenkinsfile and have a variable with report path?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to copy Jenkins Slave artifact to master. You can use following plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

You can use following method for declarative pipeline jobs:

```
stages {
 stage('Copy Archive') {
     steps {
         script {
             step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
             projectName: 'Create_archive',
             filter: "packages/infra*.zip",
             target: 'Infra']);
         }
     }
 }
```